# How to build 32-bit application on 64-bit system using Nix package manager?

Tags: cross-compilation, 32bit, nixos, nix

It seems Nix should be able to install and build 32-bit packages on 64-bit systems. It's caches already store whole nixpkgs tree built for i686 architecture, and there should be no problem to download and install them, but I can't see the way to do so.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't already know how to build separate package with nix, [here is instruction](http://sandervanderburg.blogspot.ru/2014/07/managing-private-nix-packages-outside.html).

**nixpkgs** define special variable [pkgsi686Linux](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/5ba24cc8ea7c3979a174142393d155bbc32167cf/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix#L164) for i686 packages tree and [callPackage_i686](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/5ba24cc8ea7c3979a174142393d155bbc32167cf/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix#L166) for invoking arbitrary nix-expression with overrided `system="i686-linux"`. Their usage is pretty straightforward.

Method one:

```
jsoncpp06_32 = nixpkgs.callPackage_i686 ./jsoncpp06.nix { };
```

method two:

```
myPackage32 = pkgs.pkgsi686Linux.stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "myPackage-i686-0.0.1";

    boost155 = nixpkgs.pkgsi686Linux.boost155;
    buildInputs = [
        pkgs.gcc_multi
        pkgs.python2
        pkgs.pkgconfig

        pkgs.pkgsi686Linux.ffmpeg_2_2
        pkgs.pkgsi686Linux.boost155
        pkgs.pkgsi686Linux.openssl
        pkgs.pkgsi686Linux.curl
        pkgs.pkgsi686Linux.opencv

        jsoncpp06_32
    ];

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is also a viable solution.

**default.nix**

```
{ system ? builtins.currentSystem }:
let pkgs = import <nixpkgs> { inherit system; }
in pkgs.stdout.mkDerivation {
   # ... as usual
}
```

then you run

```
% nix-build default.nix --argstr "x86_64-linux"
```

and

```
% nix-build default.nix --argstr "i686-linux"
```

Comment: You need `--argstr system i686-linux`.